# Phonegap support in "Eclipse for mobile developers"

Tags: eclipse, html, cordova

I am using Eclipse for Mobile Developers(Version: Juno Service Release 2), as part of our requirement. Now we need to make use of PhoneGap. But in this version of Eclipse there is no support for HTML5 and JavaScript.

Is there a plugin for HTML5 development in this edition or do I need to change my Eclipse edition?

*Note: Google search didn't help me in finding a suitable answer.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IBM Worklight Studio would be of interest, but it may be more than you're strictly looking for.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/

Comment: Thanks for the help, there are lot of features in this Package, which i think i wont need at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having exactly the same issue, and so far have not found out how to 'upgrade' the 'Eclipse for Mobile Developers' version of the IDE.  You can down the WPT Eclipse package, but it has dependencies and I'm not sure what they are.

However, you can do the following:

1. Go to http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/junosr2 and download the 'Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers'
2. Once unpacked, fire up the IDE and complete the 'Download the ADT Plugin' section from http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html
3. I didn't need to complete the 'Configure the ADT Plugin', possibly because of the previous  'Eclipse for Mobile Developers'.
4. If the SDK is needed, you can download from this page, unpack and reference in the Eclipse->Preferences->Android menu item

I tried this just now, and was able to build both a native app and an HTML/Javascript app to test.

Leave a comment if this answer doesn't make sense and I'll try to help out.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was on vacation. I tried out your steps and it works perfectly. So from this we can assume that for HTML5 based appilcation its better to download the Java EE version.

Comment: Looks that way.  Really pleased to have helped out.